element.animate() using Keyframes seems to apply easing function incorrectly
I'm trying to make a CSS animation that bounces back and forth, with a pause at each end. Using the Javascript method element.animate() seems to do the trick, except that using keyframes breaks the easing function, which doesn't happen when using only CSS.
Am I using animate() wrong? Is it a bug? Why do Javascript and CSS behave differently? The animate MDN docs don't say anything about this.


const element = document.getElementById("animation")
const anim = element.animate(
  [
    { offset: 0, transform: "translateX(0)" },
    { offset: .1, transform: "translateX(0)" },
    { offset: .9, transform: "translateX(50vw)" },
    { offset: 1, transform: "translateX(50vw)" },
  ],
  {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: "ease-in-out",
    direction: "alternate",
    iterations: Infinity,
  }
);
<div id="animation">Ball</div>



Creating the same animation in CSS works with the correct easing.


const element = document.getElementById("animationJS")
const anim = element.animate(
  [
    { offset: 0, transform: "translateX(0)" },
    { offset: .1, transform: "translateX(0)" },
    { offset: .9, transform: "translateX(50vw)" },
    { offset: 1, transform: "translateX(50vw)" },
  ],
  {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: "ease-in-out",
    direction: "alternate",
    iterations: Infinity,
  }
);
#animationCSS {
    animation-name: move;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
    from {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    10% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    90% {
        transform: translateX(50vw);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(50vw);
    }
}
<div id="animationJS">Ball1</div>
<div id="animationCSS">Ball2</div>



However, I can't use CSS because I want the keyframe percentages/offsets to be changed programmatically.
Also, removing the middle two keyframes in the JS code fixes it, but it still isn't what I want.

Okay I turned it into a snippet. Are you sure you are not confused by the fact that you have this delay built into your animation currently? Because it looks like it is doing exactly what is expected, easing in and out, but with your values as they are now they might not necessary look like so. To be 100% sure: exaggerate your animation (make it 100vw or 1000px) and remove any confusing aspects to see if the easing is doing what you expect it to be (in this case, remove the .1 and .9 keyframes to make sure your easing counts the whole time). But currently: cannot replicate.

@somethinghere Okay, I see what you mean. It does seem like it's accelerating indeed. However, behaviour is notably different from CSS one: it starts and stops with a lot more speed, given the same numbers. That's why I thought the ease-in-out wasn't working. I'm still puzzled by the inconsistency.
Here is the codepen to reproduce, just delete the JS file and see how the animation changes significantly.

Just turned your CSS into a snippet and, no, they look exactly the same. And they should! I have added a merged version into my answer below and the easing animations look pretty much the same, so something else is interfering here. Easing is working as expected (if it was not and nobody noticed but you? THats just seems unlikely...)

@somethinghere I added the JS code to the CSS snippet. The difference in animation is clear between the two, without differences in the parameters. It seems pure CSS applies the easing function to the step-by-step animation, while the JS code applies the easing function across the whole animation, as you mentioned.
It seems to me like there's a bug or undocumented behaviour in the JS implementation.
Oh, you did merge them in your answer. Thing is, I want the delay... So the wierdness remains.

If I can give one more hint: unmark my answer as "the answer" so your question isn't completed and you can hopefully attract people who know something we don't? (I mean, maybe give it an upvote in return but it's fine either way - just want you to find the solution!)

Oh, I didn't know marking the answer prevented it to being discoverable. I did upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation for it to count :( new account unfortunately.

It's all good. It's not a written rule, but when an answer is marked as correct even I start ignoring the questions, as there's no need to necessarily add anything. Good luck!

I've found the solution, the corresponding JS code that works the same as the CSS one.


const element = document.getElementById("animationJS")
const anim = element.animate(
  [
    { offset: 0, transform: "translateX(0)" },
    { offset: .1, transform: "translateX(0)", easing: "ease-in-out" },
    { offset: .9, transform: "translateX(50vw)"},
    { offset: 1, transform: "translateX(50vw)" },
  ],
  {
    duration: 5000,
    direction: "alternate",
    iterations: Infinity,
  }
);
#animationCSS {
    animation-name: move;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
    from {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    10% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    90% {
        transform: translateX(50vw);
    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(50vw);
    }
}
<div id="animationJS">Ball1</div>
<div id="animationCSS">Ball2</div>



Adding the easing function only to the middle part of the animation and removing it from the whole does the trick.
I have no idea why it works like this, and I can't find this specific difference in the documentation, but at least it works.

If you remove any of the confusing aspects of the animation (as the easing goes over your whole value range, so it starts at 0 and ends at 1, which means you are missing the first 10% of the ease-in and the last 10% of the ease-out part), and make your values a little bit bigger to really see the easing in action, you will notice that it currently works as expected. It's easy to get confused by animations, definitely subtle ones.


const element = document.getElementById("animation")
const anim = element.animate(
  [
    { offset: 0, transform: "translateX(0)" },
    { offset: 1, transform: "translateX(100vw) translateX(-100%)" },
  ],
  {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: "ease-in-out",
    direction: "alternate",
    iterations: Infinity,
  }
);
#animation { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }
<div id="animation">Ball</div>



You can see this in the above snippet: speed up, slow down: ease-in-out is working as expected. I can see what you are trying to accomplish though, having a 20% break between animation timelines using a single timeline, but as far as I understand, the easing applies across your whole timeline. So due to that you might want to set up and infinite loop in order to add a delay:


async function delay( ms ){
    
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
  
}
async function loopAnimation(){
  
  const element = document.getElementById("animation")

  let direction = 'normal';
  let animation;

  while( true ){
    
    await delay(1000);
    
    // Make sure previous an animations are removed and don't stack up
    if( animation ) animation.cancel();
    
    animation = element.animate([
      { offset: 0, transform: "translateX(0)" },
      { offset: 1, transform: "translateX(100vw) translateX(-100%)" },
    ],{
      duration: 3000,
      easing: "ease-in-out",
      direction: direction,
      iterations: 1,
      fill: 'both'
    })
  
    await animation.finished;
    await delay(1000);
    
    // Reverse the animation
    direction = direction === 'normal' ? 'reverse' : 'normal';

  }

}

loopAnimation();
#animation { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; }
<div id="animation">Ball</div>



Let's merge your examples
As you can see below, the animations are 99% the same, I suppose the difference is just a slight difference in timing with JS and loading, but they run almost exactly the same (I did have to correct your animation in JS so it had .9 and not .8 as the offset):


const element = document.getElementById("animate-js")
const anim = element.animate(
  [
    { offset: 0, transform: "translateX(0)" },
    { offset: .1, transform: "translateX(0)" },
    { offset: .9, transform: "translateX(10vw)" },
    { offset: 1, transform: "translateX(10vw)" },
  ],
  {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: "ease-in-out",
    direction: "alternate",
    iterations: Infinity,
  }
);
#animate-css {
  animation-name: move;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  color: red;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  90% {
    transform: translateX(10vw);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(10vw);
  }
}
<div id="animate-js">Animate</div>
<div id="animate-css">Animate</div>



Actually, no, the weirdness is still because you trying to add a delay in the loop:


const element = document.getElementById("animate-js")
const anim = element.animate(
  [
    { offset: 0, transform: "translateX(0)" },
    { offset: 1, transform: "translateX(10vw)" },
  ],
  {
    duration: 5000,
    easing: "ease-in-out",
    direction: "alternate",
    iterations: Infinity,
  }
);
#animate-css {
  animation-name: move;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  color: red;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(10vw);
  }
}
<div id="animate-js">Animate</div>
<div id="animate-css">Animate</div>



Without that, they are perfectly in sync.

That does work, thank you very much! It's so much more complicated than it should be though. The fact that the easing applies step-by-step using CSS and on the whole animation using JS seems like a big oversight. I've updated my original question with snippets that illustrate clearly the difference between them, with the same set of parameters.

Note: you don't have to mark it as the correct answer, though, it is curious that you mention this difference. I am wondering if it has anything to with things like the composite system in JS that CSS does not suoport?
